# Shell Variable Concatenation

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

Hi i'm trying to write a script but I'm receiving a different output as expected;

```
VAR_1=username
VAR_2=password
VAR_3=fancypasWoRD@$!%(115.#
VAR_4=database

mysqldump -u $VAR_1 --password=$VAR_3 $VAR_4
```

when I run this using `bash -x script.sh` it shows as

```
VAR_1=username
VAR_2=password
VAR_3='fancypasWoRD@$!%(115.#'
VAR_4=database
mysqldump -u username '--password=fancypasWoRD@$!%(115.#' database
```

Why are there single quotes in the `VAR_3` initialization and before `--password` and at the end of the *actual* password?

Comment: It's not clear what is working and what is not working.  Consider quoting the values in the variables.  `VAR_3="fancy....."`.

Comment: One answer is simply that words containing shell metacharacters are quoted when displayed during execution with the `-x` flag. That answer probably just raises the question "Why are shell metacharacters quoted in the output of `-x`?".

Comment: Same result. In bash -x script.sh it replaces the double quotes with single quotes, and then it puts them around `--password=HERE` while the variable is _after_ `password=`

Comment: @chepner: because it *could* be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is just letting you know, that that's the literal string which is passed as parameter, and there's no further substitution:

```
$ echo \*
+ echo '*'

$ echo *
+ echo list_of_files in_my_directory
```

note: have you replaced the password in your example? because this one has a syntax error...

Comment: What syntax error? I understand it adds the single quotes in the variable initialization because it is a string. But, why is there a single quote added _before_ `password=` even though, that is not part of the variable?

Comment: `mysqldump -u username >> HERE >> '--password=fancypasWoRD@$!%(115.#' << HERE << database`

Comment: I was talking about that. Whether it's a variable initialization or not is *irrelevant*. You *do* know what single quotes do, don't you? It doesn't do any harm.